# Permission Assignments Reports

Tags: sharepoint-online, reports, audit-log-reports, third-party-software

I would like to know if there is a possibility to generate a report on the permissions that were assigned the current month on a specific SharePoint site and document library.

Example: If Owner B assigned Edit permission to user A on a specific library.
Also if owner A shared a file with user X or external users.

Where can I generate this kind of report so we can maintain and monitor the security on the site level, and library level in one glance or view?

Could you please advise?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you check the [SharePoint audit logs](https://support.microsoft.com/office/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527) to find this information.